# Return PDF from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

My situation is as follows:

I am reading and returning a PDF file from the server, which is then displayed within an `iframe`. The following code works fine with IE. However, when I access the site via Chrome, I get all junk characters.

```
while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    if (HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
            HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = true;
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";                      
            HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //HttpContext.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

When I flush the response, I do get to see the PDF correctly. The problem is that calling flush is resulting in `"Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent"` warning on the server.

Question is: Why is flush needed for Chrome and if there is a way to avoid flush? So far, I have read all the posts and unable to resolve the server error associated with flushing.

Server - IIS7, Windows Server 2008 R2

App - ASP.Net 4.0.30319.0, C#, Ajax

Comment: while didn't you use an action that returns `FileResult`?

Comment: The pdf file which is sent directly to an iFrame is then displayed inside a fancybox. Not sure if returning a FileResultwill work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you, change your controller to return `FileResult`

```
public FileResult DownloadPDF()
{
    buffer = <bytes from your PDF file>;
    return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "download.pdf");
}
```

Show PDF

```
public FileResult ShowPDF()
{
    buffer = <bytes from your PDF file>;
    return File(buffer, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: The application is such that the file should not be downloaded, but displayed within an iFrame/Fancybox. Otherwise there are other solutions that would have worked.

Comment: Then try to remove the `, "download.pdf"` part. If it doesn't have filename specified, it will display in browser - if I remember very well

Comment: Thanks. I need to display the pdf inside a fancybox.

Comment: Changing my approach from streaming to FileResult eliminated the issue.  On the surface it seems to be a bit slower than the previous approach.